# Magical 1.005 * 100 will be 100.49999999999999

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

While reading the post [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript), I found an interesting thing but I haven't figured out the reason.

```
1.005 * 100 // 100.49999999999999 (In Chrome 47.0)
1.005 * 100 // 100.49999999999999 (In Firefox 38.6)
1.005 * 100 // 100.49999999999998 (In MSIE 11)
2.005 * 100 // 200.5 (In all browsers)
```

What is the rounding issue of JS interpreter with the magical 1.005?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/2792083